# Create Multidimensional Array collector - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to create a "array collector" to retrieve data from a huge array without doing foreach loops, and stuff like that time after time. I have no clue where to start so i was wondering if someone knows if there is a package that already has my purposes or that i need something custom made. Can someone help me out with this?

I have a array (see example 1), and if i insert a specific array (see example 2) i want to retrieve al the items that i have selected. For the output please see example 3. Can someone get me started or create something like it? If someone creates this, ill make a github package for it with all credits to the author, cause i think this can help a lot of people!

I am familiar with Laravel Collections but they dont provide any stuff with the method i would like to.

#### Example 1

```
$array = [
        'title'       => 'Product Title',
        'description' => 'Lorem ipsum item text ',
        'variants'    => [
            0 => [
                'title'       => 'Variant title 1',
                'description' => 'Lorem variant description',
                'price'       => [
                    'price'     => 10,
                    'price_old' => 14
                ]
            ],
            1 => [
                'title'       => 'Variant title 2',
                'description' => 'Lorem variant description',
                'price'       => [
                    'price'     => 10,
                    'price_old' => 14
                ],
                'colors'      => [
                    0 => 'Red',
                    1 => 'Blue'
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

#### Example 2

```
$get = [ 'title', 'variants.title', 'variants.price.price', 'variants.colors' ];
```

#### Example 3

```
    $array = [
        'title'       => 'Product Title',
        'variants'    => [
            0 => [
                'title'       => 'Variant title 1',
                'price'       => [
                    'price'     => 10,
                ]
            ],
            1 => [
                'title'       => 'Variant title 2',
                'price'       => [
                    'price'     => 10,
                ],
                'colors'      => [
                    0 => 'Red',
                    1 => 'Blue'
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution would be implementing the RecursiveArrayIterator class
http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job. There are 2 loops nested inside each other. The first loop will only iterate count($get) times, and the second by the depth of the element. In the example you gave, there would only be 8 loops total. You could add some error handling if !empty(), etc. I set the array by reference (&) to prevent the array from duplicating in memory in case you get a large dataset.

```
function getValues(&$array, $get) {
    $outputs = [];
    foreach ($get as $query) {
        $query = explode('.', $get);
        $container &= $array;
        foreach ($query as $elem) {
            $container &= $comtainer[$elem];
        }
    }
}
```